# $expode_top[] & $expode_bottom[] usage

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, explode

I'm rewriting a PHP plugin, and there are functions called `$expode_top[]` & `$expode_bottom[]`. I understand what the normal explode function does, but what are these?

It seems to be impossible to find an answer on Google because it replaces the underscore with a space.

Comment: My advice to you is learn more php before rewrite the plugin, if you aren't able to distinguish the difference between an array and a function, you cant do a good work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are array variables, not functions, they just happen to start with a keyword you are familiar with. Anything beginning with a `$` is a variable in PHP.

Using `[]` will put the assigned variable into the "next" position of the array. For example:

```
$expode_top = array();
$expode_top[] = "testing";

if ( $expode_top[0] == "testing" ){
    echo "it does equal testing";
}
```

As @gwillie rightly commented, it could also be a variable function - the name of the variable is replaced and then that function is executed. Second example:

```
$expode_top = "echo";
$expode_top("testing");
```

Is functionally the same as:

```
echo("testing");
```

Comment: Or a `variable function` as in `$explode_top()`

Answer (score 0):

Those are array variable names, not functions, as indicated by the $ and []. Also, neither exists as a function.